# Run flow on prefect cloud without running local agent locally?

Tags: python, deployment, prefect

I'm trying to deploy my flow but I'don't know what I should do to completely deploy it (serverless).

I'm using the free tier of Prefect Cloud and I have create a storage and process block.

The step I have done :

- Build deployment

```
$ prefect deployment build -n reporting_ff_dev-deployment flow.py:my_flow
```

- Apply configuration

```
$ prefect deployment apply <file.yaml>
```

- Create block

```
from prefect.filesystems import LocalFileSystem
from prefect.infrastructure import Process

#STORAGE
my_storage_block = LocalFileSystem(
    basepath='~/ff_dev'
)
my_storage_block.save(
    name='ff-dev-storage-block',
    overwrite=True)

#INFRA
my_process_infra = Process(
    working_dir='~/_ff_dev_work',
)
my_process_infra.save(
    name='ff-dev-process-infra',
    overwrite=True)
```

- deploy block

```
$ prefect deployment build -n <name>  -sb <storage_name> -ib <infra_name>  <entry_point.yml> -a
```

I know that prefect cloud is a control system rather than a storage medium but as I understand,  a store block -> store the code and process code -> run the code. What is the next step to run the flow without local agent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you looking for the code to be executed from?
With a deployment registered, you can execute the following to spawn a flow run. A deployment just describes how and where -

prefect deployment run /my_flow

Comment: I was trying to deploy it on prefect cloud, as I thought I could do it this way with the storage and process block. I'm using GitHub Action to execute deploy it now.

Comment: Hi there - at this time, Prefect doesn't actually _execute_ your code, it schedules it to be executed. 

The storage block says where to upload / download flow and results.
The process block says to run this bit of code as a sub-process wherever the agent is running.
The key here is that there needs to be an agent that receives the flow_run, and then spawns it - with the given parameters.

More aptly - Prefect isn't like a Lambda function where you write the code and it executes Prefect cloud side - it's up to you to supply the infrastructure it executes on.